# How to implement click event for panel in sencha touch in controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to implement clickor tap  event for panel in sencha touch in controller

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.controller.details', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    stores : ['your store'],
    models : ['your model'],
    refs: {
        myContainer: 'your view'
    },
    control: {
        'your view': {
            activate: 'onActivate',// fires when view is activated
            itemtap: 'onItemTap',// fires when item is tapped
        }
    }
},
onActivate: function() {
    console.log('Main container is active');
},

onItemTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
    console.log('Item was tapped on the Data View');
    console.log(view, index, target, record, event);
    Ext.Msg.alert('', 'The user  selected is: ' + record.get('username'));
},
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Implement tap of Panel like this. It will work.

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.text', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'text',
initialize: function () {
    this.element.on({
        tap: function () { alert('tapped!'); }
    });
}
```

});